# How to get data on initState - Flutter Web Behavior

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting a variable (number 4999 as example) from Firebase into the initState as follows:

```
class AsyncInitTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AsyncInitTestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _AsyncInitTestPageState createState() => _AsyncInitTestPageState();
}


class _AsyncInitTestPageState extends State<AsyncInitTestPage> {

  LoteActualBloc estanqueBloc = LoteActualBloc();

  String numtext = 'Previous';

@override
  void dispose() {
    estanqueBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
void initState() {
    _getNumberOnce();
  super.initState();  
}


Future<void> _getNumberOnce() async {
  int _num = await estanqueBloc.getNumber();
  numtext = _num.toString();
  print('Number on InitState $numtext');
  setState(() {});
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print('Number on Build $numtext');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Async InitState Test'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Firebase RTDB query is pretty simple:

```
 Future<int> getNumber() async {

  Query resp = db.child('PATH/number');
    return resp.once().then((snapshot) => (snapshot.snapshot.value as dynamic));
}
```

On mobile, I am getting the data as expected...

> flutter: Number on Build Previous
>
> flutter: Number on InitState 4999
>
> flutter: Number on Build 4999

When I execute the same code on Web, I'm not getting the data...

> Number on Build Previous

**Are there differences in async functions in Web and Mobile?**

**How can I fix the code so that it works correctly in both environments (Web & Mobile)?**

**APPEND:**

I am using `firebase_database version: ^9.0.8` and `Flutter 2.10.3`. Before updating Flutter and using version 8.2.0 the code worked correctly in both environments.

If I downgrade to firebase_database^8.2.0, and make the corresponding changes (snapshot.value instead snapshot.snapshot.value) the queries work fine on Web again

Comment: There *should* be no difference in async behavior between the platforms, but bugs are always possible of course. I see no calls to the Firebase Realtime Database API in the code in your question though, so it's hard to see where the problem comes from. --- I recommend reproducing the problem without any wrapper classes and functions, just calling the Firebase API that isn't working for you and printing the results that show the unexpected difference between platforms.

Comment: Thank you @puf. I added the Firebase Realtime Query in the Question. At this point, I'm not really sure if the problem is in the Firebase Query or if it's in the async management on initState (Flutter)

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I don't see any reason why the code would work differently between web and Android/iOS. Can you merge the two code snippets into a [single, minimal piece of code that works differently between the two platforms that any of us can copy/paste and run as is to get the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Having the JSON from `PATH/estanques` in your database would also help for that. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks @puf. I simplified the code to make it very easy to understand (I hope). In this case, the JSON is just a number (4999).

Comment: Hmm... I don't see an immediate error, but am thinking whether the type coercion could be different. Can you try to return the native value of the snapshot, so `snapshot.snapshot.value as dynamic` instead of casting/rounding it to an `int`?

Comment: @puf. The same thing happens. I have tried even getting full lists with Firebase List and the behavior is the same

Comment: Darn.... I'm really not sure what's going on in that case. I hope somebody else spots it (or I somehow find a moment to try and reproduce it) :-/

Comment: Thanks @puf. I did some additional testing by changing the firebase query command in `_getNumberOnce` to a decoy of type `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3))` and through the prints I can see that it successfully passed through initState and `_getNumberOnce`. So it is most likely a Firebase issue or a combination of the Firebase update and the Flutter update. If this is so, I am afraid that Flutter and Firebase based web developments will fail when updated.

Comment: @puf. I have reason to believe that this problem occurs not only on the web but also on mobile devices, with the added downside that it is occasional (about once in 20), making the problem more difficult to pinpoint.

Comment: @puf. I decided to downgrade to firebase_database^8.2.0 and got it working fine again on Web. I kept the version of flutter at the most recent (2.10.3), so the problem is indeed focused on Firebase.